# jQuery arranged index input name[?]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want after remove input arranged index input name, for example:

After remove input `row222[2]` others input name as: `row000[0]` & `row111[1]` & `row333[2]`
After remove input `row333[3]` others input name as: `row000[0]` & `row111[1]` & `row222[2]`
After remove input `row111[3]` others input name as: `row000[0]` & `row222[1]` & `row333[2]`
etc...

What do i do?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/chtvfkt2/)

My full code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.RemOve', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.CloSe').remove();

    $('.CloSe').each(function(idx) {
        var Input = $($('.Change input'), this);
        Input.each(function(i) {
            var str = $(this).attr('name');
            var currentIdx = parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
            $(this).attr('name', str.replace(currentIdx, idx));
        })
    });
    $('.CloSe').each(function(){
        $('.namein', this).empty().append($(this).find('input').prop('name'))
    })
})
```

```css
.RemOve{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows[0]</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows000[0]"> // rows000[0]
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows[1]</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows111[1]"> // rows111[1]
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows[2]</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows222[2]"> // rows222[2]
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows[3]</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows333[3]"> // rows333[3]
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code, check out here http://jsfiddle.net/chtvfkt2/1/

And I also commented on some of your codes. If there's a specific reason for using the commented codes, just uncomment and use it.

---

**UPDATE**

I'm a bit confused by your question. So I split the answers.

If you want to rename the rest of the elements after getting rid of one of them, take this below.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.RemOve', function(e) {
    //I see no point in using preventDefault() here ?
    //e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.CloSe').remove();
    
    $('.CloSe').each(function(idx, element) {
        
        //var Input = $($('.Change input'), this);
        
        //Improved :: better than using 'this'.
        var Input = $($('.Change input'), element); 
        Input.each(function(i, el) {
            
            //Improved :: No point using parseInt and str.replace ?
            //var str = $(this).attr('name');
            //var currentIdx = parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
            //$(this).attr('name', str.replace(currentIdx, idx));            
            
            
            var numb = i < 99 ? "rows00" + i : "rows0" + i;
            if ( i > 100 ) {
                numb = "rows" + i;
            }            
            $(el).attr('name', numb);
        })
    });
        
    $('.CloSe').each(function(){
        $('.namein', this).empty().append($(this).find('input').prop('name'))
    });

    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows000</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows000">
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows001</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows001">
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows002</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows002">
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows003</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows003">
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
```

Or if you want to just chop one of them off and expect no changes, take this.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.RemOve', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.CloSe').remove();     
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows000</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows000">
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows001</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows001">
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows002</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows002">
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows003</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows003">
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
```

---

**FINAL UPDATE**

Just replcaing display text was what you wanted, this code will do.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.RemOve', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.CloSe').remove();
    
    $('.CloSe').each(function(idx, element) {        
        //Improved :: better than using 'this'.
        var Input = $($('.Change input'), element); 
        Input.each(function(i, el) {            
            var numb = i < 99 ? "rows00" + i : "rows0" + i;
            if ( i > 100 ) {
                numb = "rows" + i;
            }            
            $(el).prev().text(numb);
        })
    });    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows000</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows000">
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows001</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows001">
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows002</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows002">
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
<div class="CloSe">
    <span class="Change">
        <b class="namein">rows003</b>
        <input type="text" name="rows003">
    </span>
    <span class="RemOve">Remove</span>
</div>
```

Comment: tanx, i want change number between '[*]' no name input, my input is array, over code is a example: row333[HERE]

Comment: I changed it as:http://jsfiddle.net/chtvfkt2/4/ but my code don't work. I want arranged index input name for: rows[**index**]

Comment: @TaylorGomez I just don't get it. I already gave you a correct answer for both ways. Are you telling me that those names should be with the brackets `[    ]`?

Comment: yes, The digit(number) in brackets can be arranged?
I want putting the Identical digit(number) of Inside in inputs (two inputs: **wewe[???] && rows[???]**) each class name **CloSe** for example after remove: CloSe 1: wewe[1] && rows[1] && CloSe 2: wewe[2] && rows[2] && CloSe 1: wewe[3] && rows[3] && etc... EDIT DEMO CODES: http://jsfiddle.net/chtvfkt2/4/

Comment: Your question has just got advanced, you know that? It looks like a joke to me now. What's even worse is that you're not trying anything for getting through your own problem. Plus, I can hardly understand your English. Just try it, I already gave you a hint. I'm out of here. Good luck.